# Get shared preferences specific value last updated date and time

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, cache-expiration

I am using shared preferences to store userId once user login to the app. I need to expire(delete) the stored userId after 30 days once the userId is stored on shared preferences. 
Is it possible to get the last modified date and time of specific shared preference value.

Comment: can't you add this info in the SharedPreference as well?

Comment: @Blackbelt, I can add it. But I wanted to know is there any way to get last modified date time for shared preferences value.

Comment: you can get the last time the file was accessed, but no one can give you the assurance that it was accessed to write a particular information

Comment: No. That is not possible. You must save the date/time yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, `SharedPreferences` don't have any built in method to do this. You'll have to store last modification date manually, possible in `SharedPreferences` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can get the path of the SharedPreferences file and try using `lastModified()` of File class like,

```
File file = new File("path of shared-preference file");
file.lastModified();
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually you could create an `Alarm`: you can set it to run within 30 days from the "registration" for the value stored in `SharedPreferences`.
You can then use a Receiver (search for more examples) to catch the alarm and run your code.
An example [here](https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223)